# Batch check if mapped network drive exists

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm currently writing a script that should map a network drive to the letter `Z` , i'm using the command 
`net use z: \\path` , the thing is that if the user is already using this letter i won't be able to map it, is there any way to check the existense of this drive (z) and if it exists to unmount it and mount it to a different letter and still use the `z` drive which i need for my script, this is a part of an installation, and it should be on Z drive.

Comment: Start with `for /F "tokens=1,2*" %G in ('net use^|Find "\\"^|Find /I "Z:"') do @echo %H %I` to see an example. (Using that in a batch script, double the `%` sign, use `%%G`, `%%H` etc.) [Learn more ...](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Then you could replace that simple `@echo %%H %%I` with [multiple commands in FOR loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html). Feel free to [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27246899/edit) with actual achievements and ask more in case you crane at something.

Comment: Why not just use the next available drive letter intead of destroying the users current drive mapping: `net use * \\path`. or you can use the PUSHD command which will map the next available drive letter and immediately do a change directory to that path: `PUSHD \\path`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can check whether the drive is mounted by `IF EXIST Z:\`. This should work:

```
if exist z:\ (
    net use z: /delete
)
net use z: \\path
```

Comment: Also useful: `if not exist z:\ (net use z: \\my\unc\path)`

Comment: This only answers part of the question and does not answer the full question of re-mapping the drive to a different letter.

Comment: Note; If you have a disconnected (but still remembered) mapped drive, it doesn't show up when accessed this way.  I haven't found a workaround / ended up just removing the if condition and deleting the mapped drive regardless of whether or not one existed)

Answer (score 5):

I use the following scriptbit to unmap all drives:

```
:: First unmap all network drives
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%G IN ('net use^| Find "\\"') DO (
  ECHO.Unmapping %%I from drive letter %%H
  NET USE %%H /D > NUL
)
```

What does it do? Let's split this up

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%G IN () DO ()--> will iterate over the set defined between () and the first, second and third word (any whitespace is used as separator) will become available as %%G, %%H and %%I respectively.

('...') will run a command ... and pass the result(s) to the FOR loop

net use will output something like this:

```
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           M:        \\diskstation\music       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           P:        \\diskstation\home        Microsoft Windows Network
OK           V:        \\diskstation\video       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\diskstation\photo       Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

This output is then piped to Find.exe (the windows equivalent to grep) which looks for "\\".

The pipe symbol | is escaped using ^ so cmd does not execute it directly. The output will then be:

```
OK           M:        \\diskstation\music       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           P:        \\diskstation\home        Microsoft Windows Network
OK           V:        \\diskstation\video       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\diskstation\photo       Microsoft Windows Network
```

NET USE /D will delete the drive mapping for the selected mapping

Comment: First, this does nothing to answer the posters question.  Second, this breaks if the remote UNC path is long and causes the network column to display on a second line.  This script is overkill for deleting all drive mappings.  A simpler way to remove all drive mappings is to use net use * /d /y.

Comment: Third, it'll break, if *Status* is not *OK* and consists of multiple words e. g. `Not available`. Then `tokens` will catch the wrong parts.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible way could be:

```
net use Z:
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 net use Z: /delete
net use Z: \\path
```

Comment: I like this because you can use it with just a share too, e.g. `net use \\some\share`

Answer (score 3):

My requirements were slightly different than the OP's: I needed to map a network drive, always to the same path, but only if it didn't exist already

```
if not exist z:\ (
    net use z: \\ComputerName\ShareName
)
```

Comment: z: may be in Disconnected or Unavailable state, in this case remapping may fail.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question, you can check if Z is already mapped and then re-map it to a different drive letter (e.g. y:), then map z to the new path.

```
if exist z:\ (
    for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('net use^|Find "\\"^|Find /I "z:"')  do ( net use y: %%H )
    net use z: /delete
)
net use z: \\path
```

Comment: As already commented below similar answers, `if exist z:\` does not check if a drive letter is just mapped. Instead, it returns true if a drive letter is mapped AND if the destination is available. So with your solution, you cannot delete a mapped drive, that is currently unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

In batch you can write code like this:

```
@echo off
net use V: >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto unmap
```

if exist `V:\` does not work on Windows 10, also `net use` displays additional information, I have now suppressed it using `>nul 2>&1`.